# Java : Strictly type checking fails?

Tags: java, typechecking

Suppose I have two classes as follows

```
class A
{
  private Double value;
  ...
  //getters and setters
}

class B
{
  private Double value;
  ...
  //getters and setters
}
```

**Update**

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    A a = new A();
    B b = new B();
    a.setValue(b.getValue() != null ? b.getValue() : 0); //works!
    a.setValue(0); //doesn't work
}
```

And the statement

1. `a.setValue(b.getValue != null ? b.getValue : 0);` works fine but
2. `a.setValue(0)` doesn't works I need to set the value as `0D` to make it work.

why I need not write a `D` along with `0` in first case?

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. We can't easily tell what's going on here.

Comment: Thats because 0 is considered a integer type by compiler and integer cannot be assigned to double directly, hence you need to specify `D` so to tell compiler that it's a double value.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have updated the some more code, hope that is helpful for you

Comment: That's still not a short but complete example. In particular, if your setters took `double` instead of `Double`, it would be fine. I've written an answer based on my *expectation*, but in future please provide *complete* examples. (It would only have taken a few more lines of code to turn this into something we could copy, paste and compile...)

Comment: yes sure that will really be helpful for me and the one who is answering. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I *suspect* the problem is that you've got

```
setValue(Double value)
```

Now the type of your conditional expression (`b.getValue() != null ? b.getValue() : 0`) is `double`, following the rules of [JLS section 15.25.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25.2):

> If one of the operands is of type `T`, where `T` is `Byte`, `Short`, or `Character`, and the other operand is a constant expression of type int whose value is representable in the type `U` which is the result of applying unboxing conversion to `T`, then the type of the conditional expression is `U`.

... and that's fine, because you're then calling `setValue` with a `double` argument, and that can be boxed to `Double`.

However, when you try calling `setDouble(0)` you're trying to call `setValue` with an `int` argument, and that *can't* be boxed to `Double`... hence the error, and hence the success when you pass `0D` instead.

Note that you don't need method calls etc to demonstrate this - here's a simple example:

```
Double x = 0d;        
Double y = true ? x : 0; // Fine
Double z = 0; // Error
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as a supplement to Jon's answer, I recommend that you *only* use the primitive wrapper types for fields, variables and parameter types when they are actually required.

It is generally more efficient to use the corresponding primitive types.  And there are fewer "edge cases" to trip you up / make your code more fragile.

(One of the edge cases is that the semantics of `==` are ... non-intuitive.  Another is that you can get mysterious `NullPointerException` in situations where the primitive types wouldn't / couldn't give you that.)